# How to access LocalDB without SqlServer from a winforms app c#?

Tags: database, winforms, windows-installer, connection-string, localdb

**Scenario:**

I have programmatically created a Database on Master using an appropriate connection string and added tables to it. But when I tried to access it to create a stored procedure I cannot as it says, it does not have access to perform any action on DB.

I used this query with C# and tried to create the stored procedure.

```
//Connection String ("Server=localhost;Integrated security=SSPI;database=master") => For Createing Database

//Connection String ("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\\MyAppDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True") => For trying to create stored procedure on already created Local DB

string AccountEmail = "CREATE PROCEDURE [MyAppDB].[dbo].[usp_AccountEmail]( @Email varchar(max)) AS SELECT Username FROM [dbo].[User] WHERE Email = @Email";
                    SqlCommand mySP = new SqlCommand(AccountEmail, sqlcon);
```

using `[MyAppDB].[dbo].[usp_AccountEmail]` resulted in Exception of specifying the database name. But when I tried the same like `[dbo].[usp_AccountEmail]` it executed and created a stored procedure on master but that's not what I want, I want it to be created on localDB.

**The Problem:**

I want to add a stored procedure to the already created database and I want to use the DB without installing any SQL Packages by the client. Just clean install of my app and run which connects to the local DB which is created programmatically by my app. I am struggling with attaching the DB with the installer and if I even do the connection string from the app cannot get the proper path of the attached DB which the client chooses (not definite).

**Common Question:**

1. is there any common approach to attach local DB with the set of files to the installer so that the client doesn't need to install any other packages?

**The Goal:**

All I want is to create an installer that has DB and AppData which does not require any additional packages to be installed and the app uses the DB to store and retrieve the data plus the database already has tables and stored procedures.

Please Help me with this Guys. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you don't need to install sql server, that is correct, but you will need to install the driver needed to connect to localdb.

Comment: is it available when with the app when we create the installer? @GuidoG .Thanks for commenting, I thought this question will go to waste of time.

Comment: I am sure some installers can do this, you will have to search for that. [This link(https://www.sqlshack.com/install-microsoft-sql-server-express-localdb/) might be usefull to you